# Water main entry change from1/2" to bigger to change pressure

Tags: water

I change main entry from 1/2" to bigger and the rest of home piping still1/2 " will it change pressure or all piping has to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between pressure and flow rate.

Pressure is the power with which the water presses against valves; this won't change with the diameter of the pipes.

Flow rate is how much water comes out at a time, this will get better depending on the smallest diameter along the run and which other taps are open (in other words the smallest choke point). So if the entry is large up until the first branch at least then it will increase flow rate when both sides are being used but not for an individual tap.

Answer (score 1):

You will get improved performance, even if the piping in the house has not been "upgraded".

There are two different types of "pressure" that are relevant to this situation. The first is the static pressure. This is the pressure when no water is being used. This is generally between 50 and 80 PSI, and it is never effected by pipe size. The other is dynamic pressure, which is the pressure measured while water is flowing.

For a given pipe size and water flow rate, the water pressure drop is proportional to pipe length. For example, see table 6 of [The Copper Tube Handbook](http://www.copper.org/publications/pub_list/pdf/copper_tube_handbook.pdf). So, when you're flowing a given amount of water, you'll have a higher dynamic pressure when using larger diameter pipe. Note also that water should also have some maximum velocity in the pipe (or else the water will etch the pipe). For 1/2 inch pipe, a maximum of 5 gpm should be used, and would generate a loss of about 0.13 PSI per foot of pipe.

So, getting back to the original question: Replacing the service pipe provides a higher dynamic pressure at your house. Leaving the in-house piping as is leaves the pressure loss in the house unchanged. So, overall a higher dynamic pressure can be delivered to the house's fixtures (as long as the final pressure is above some minimum.... perhaps 10 PSI).